# OpenVPN "Cannot pre-load keyfile" after moved conf to /etc/openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I have succesfully configured OpenVPN with a *server.conf* that I runned with the `openvpn` executable, e.g. `openvpn --config server.conf`.

However, when I tried to move this file to `/etc/openvpn` in order to daemonize it and run my vpn server on boot, I got the error reported in title using the command `journalctl -xeu openvpn@server.service`.

I think that's because of file permissions, but I don't know how I should change them.

```bash
ago 28 11:22:03 ovpn-server[4493]: Warning: Error redirecting stdout/stderr to --log file: /home/cristiano/my-openvpn/logs/server.log: No such file or directory (errno=2)
ago 28 11:22:03 ovpn-server[4493]: Cannot pre-load keyfile (/home/cristiano/my-openvpn/keys/ta.key)
ago 28 11:22:03 ovpn-server[4493]: Exiting due to fatal error
```

Permissions for both `server.log` and `ta.key` files are `-rw/-/-`, and they belong to user and group `cristiano`.

Since I don't want these files to be public, how can I give them the least privileges to be able to spawn the server?

EDIT: Even after changing permissions for both files to 777, it does not work, so I really don't know what's going on.

If it can help, I'm using `user nobody` and `group nogroup` in *server.conf*. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue.

I transferred all the `.key` `.pem` `.crt` files from `../server` to `../client`, gave them `777`, specified the absolute path in `server.conf` and everything is worked.

But not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).